# Override the antd table top left cell

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am trying to override or udpate the cell in the example below (a table with expandable rows):
https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-breeze-fds1b

Im trying to add a icon in the left most cell of the header to expand/contract all rows. Any suggestions on how to do this?  I see the documentation to override a component using the component prop but I'm not very familiar on how I might be to update a given cell (in header):

```
<Table
  components={...}
/>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

What you want is possible, although a bit tedious. To do this, you'll have to include the open row keys as part of React state and control row expansion directly. Something like this (using hooks):

```
const [expandedRowKeys, setExpandedRowKeys] = React.useState([]); // Collapse all rows by default

const onExpansion = (isExpanded, record) => {
   if (isExpanded)
     setExpandedRowKeys([ ...expandedRowKeys, record.key]);
   else
     setExpandedRowKeys(expandedRowKeys.filter(key !== record.key));
}

const collapseAllRows = () => setExpandedRowKeys([])

const expandAllRows = () => setExpandedRowKeys(yourTableRecords.map(record => record.key));

return (
  <Table
    ...
    expandedRowRender={record => getExpansionContent()}
    expandedRowKeys={expandedRowKeys}
    onExpand={onExpansion}
  />
  <button onClick={expandAllRows}>Expand All</button>
  <button onClick={collapseAllRows}>Collpse All</button>
```

EDIT: As for putting the button(s) for expanding/collapsing all rows in the "expansion-icons column" at the top-left, `antd` does not provide any support for this, it's only supported for row-selection. If you really need such an implementation, it will have to be outside `antd`. you'll have to create the `<Checkbox />` manually, use your CSS to position it in that top-left row (might have to use negative margins) and assign the handlers for expanding/collapsing all rows.

It is a hack, but it's the only way of achieving this, at the moment

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I don't have a problem with being able to expand/collapse rows.  Its more about being able to put the icon in the top left cell.

Comment: Did you find a way to put the button there?

Answer (score 1):

You can use render method in the column and return an icon.
Also You can use fixed to display column at fixed position.

```
const columns = [{
    title: 'Name',
    dataIndex: 'name',
    key: 'name',
    fixed: 'left',
    render: text => <Icon/>,
  },
];
```